# Want to update Listview in Android without refershing the Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have displayed some data in a Listview using ListAdapter. Now I want the listview to refresh automatically after x seconds. How can this be done?
I am using AsyncTask to fetch data from Server.

I have tried this:

```
public void reloadDeviceData() {
    handler.postDelayed(runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GetDevices().execute();          // this method will contain your almost-finished HTTP calls
            handler.postDelayed(this, TIME);
        }
    }, TIME);
}
```

What is happening is that the listview does not refresh but instead add items after the current listview.
GetDevices is the class which extends AsyncTask here.

Comment: Can you post the code of your `GetDevices` task?

Comment: you can set notifydatasetchanged() with your adater when u get fresh data

Comment: Does notifydatasetchanged() check data in realtime?

Comment: yes it does....

Comment: using listview is not a ggod practice..please use recycler view

Comment: notifydatasetchanged actually just refresh your adapter binding all items again in your listview, so when you have new data in your list you should call notifydatasetchanged or notifyitemchanged to refresh your view

Answer (score 0):

When you get the response from API. just update the adapter list by using follwing  line `adapter.list.clear()` then after `adapter.list.addAll(apiList)` and then after You just have to notify the listview adapter.

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend :

1. use recyclerview for performance point of view .
2. Check Delta difference between new and old list and add /update those items only. For difference you can use either basic collections class methods or DiffUittls lib